# What am I doing wrong? Can't call earlier functions

Tags: python

```
def addition(num1, num2):
    answerAdd=num1+num2
    print(answerAdd)
def subtraction(num1, num2):
    answerSub=num1-num2
    print(answerSub)
def main():
    num1=int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2=int(input('Enter the second number: '))
    print(addition, subtraction)
main()
```

I've tried renaming the call function and can't get it to return the arithmetic,.

Comment: You aren't calling them at all. The functions don't automatically get called with variables using the same names as the parameters as its arguments. `num1` and `num2` inside `main` have nothing to do with the function parameters.

Comment: Use `print(addition(num1, num2), subtraction(num1, num2))`.

Comment: @BokiX No, because neither `addition` nor  `subtraction` return a value to print.

Comment: Then he can just call them like `addition(num1, num2)` and `subtraction(num1, num2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems:

1. `print` and `return` are not interchangeable. When you need your function to return a value you use `return`, when you merely need it to print something than use `print`. Your first two functions should be returning the values they calculate so that your `main()` function can `print()` them.
2. When calling your functions you have to give them values for the arguments you defined. Your `addition` and `subtraction` functions both have two arguments.

---

```
def addition(num1, num2):
    answerAdd=num1+num2
    #Problem 1: changed to `return`
    return answerAdd

def subtraction(num1, num2):
    answerSub=num1-num2
    #Problem 1: changed to `return`
    return answerSub

def main():
    num1=int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    num2=int(input('Enter the second number: '))
    #Problem 2: changed to send `num1` and `num2` as arguments to both functions
    print(addition(num1, num2), subtraction(num1, num2))

main()
```

Comment: Thank you! This was an incredibly helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send the two parameters to the two functions:

```
print(addition(num1, num2), subtraction(num1, num2))
```

Comment: Both functions print, rather than returning, the values, so the outer call to `print` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you. That's very obvious. I apologize for the silly question....